Generate Markdown file without __init__.py in subfolders with MkDocstrings
So this is my project structure :
- packages
  --pkg1
  ---subpkg1
  ----wrkpkg1
  ------file1.py
  ----wrkpkg2
  ------file2.py
  ----__init__.py

mkdocs.yaml:
plugins:

search
glightbox # lightbox for images
include-markdown # allows to include other files from within a markdown file
kroki: # allows to render diagrams from text, including PlantUML
ServerURL: https://ace-diagrams.devcloud.abb.com/
FencePrefix: ''
gen-files:
scripts:

Scripts/gen_ref_pages.py


literate-nav:
nav_file: summary.md
section-index
mkdocstrings

when I am doing mkdocs build am getting the following error
ERROR   -  Could not collect 'packages.pkg1.subpkg1.wrkpkg1.file1'
Aborted with a BuildError!
ERROR   -  Could not collect 'packages.pkg1.subpkg1.wrkpkg2.file2'
Aborted with a BuildError!
I know the issue is with wrkpkg1 is not having init.py
My question is, is there any way to generate md files when I am having subfolders without init files, as in standard I will not be needing init in all my subfolders
I tried subpackages: true in mkdocs.yaml files, tried adding init file (it worked but having 20+ init files when I dont need to act them as a package is purely not a good structure)
I need to generate md files automatically and the subfolders should not be having the init files. My main folder subpkg1 is having the necessary init file
